# Nest Aggregation with dynamic fields - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

Is it possible to use nest to create buckets with keywords/fields that are not strongly typed?

Due to the nature of this project. I do not have any root objects to pass in.
Below is an example.

```
            var result = client.Search<PortalDoc>(s => s
                        .Aggregations(a => a
                            .Terms("agg_objecttype", t => t.Field(l => "CUSTOM_FIELD_HERE"))
                        )     
                    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`string` implicitly convert to `Field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html), so you can pass a string for any field name

```
var result = client.Search<PortalDoc>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("agg_objecttype", t => t
            .Field("CUSTOM_FIELD_HERE")
        )
    )     
);
```

Comment: that easy huh? Quick question. I am getting an error "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default". I know you can usually put .Suffix("Keyword") on the end of the field and it makes it go away. Anyway to do that with the string?

Comment: Use `"CUSTOM_FIELD_HERE.Keyword"` (replace `Keyword` with whatever the keyword sub field is called)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like that is possible. Looks [here](https://gist.github.com/2e3s/c69635f822565a91a9b2) for my solution using nested fields. It allows to do all the operations on "dynamic" fields, but with somewhat greater efforts (nested fields are tougher to manipulate with). The gist has some proofs for search, but I implemented aggregations as well.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/something -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "live" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : true },
            "dynamic" : false,
            "properties" : {
                "customFields" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "fieldName" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                        "stringValue": {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "fields" : {
                                "raw" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
                            }
                        },
                        "integerValue": { "type" : "long" },
                        "floatValue": { "type" : "double" },
                        "datetimeValue": { "type" : "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd" },
                        "booleanValue": { "type" : "boolean" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Search should be done in the same nested query using AND, and aggregations should be done in nested aggregation.
I made it for dynamic fields, but it probably can be adjusted for something else. I doubt there can be more flexibility with searchable/aggregatable fields due to principles how indices work.